# Chi Square distribution with Gamma

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I've see similar question but I didn't receive the answer I was looking for. 
Example: I am given the moment generating function for a Chi-Square distribution. If I am looking for P(1<= X <=2) when I go to fill out f(x) =$$ (1/((\Gamma)(r/2)2^{r/2}))x^{r/2-1}e^{-x/2}$$
    What do I assume that Gamma is? I also know that \m = 6 and \sigma ^2 = 12

Comment: I tried editing this and I can't seem to get it. It's the Chi-Square formula.

Comment: Gamma (here $\Gamma(r/2)$) is a function: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function. This link shows particular values/formulas when $r$ is an integer.

Comment: So Gamma is just (n-1)!   So easy, thank you!